# S3 boto - list objects in parallel

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, botocore

I want to quickly (in parallel?) list directory/prefix with 100K+ objects.

The pagination works (see below) but I'm unable to get `NextKeyMarker` until I download the last page - it breaks the idea of parallelization.
Ideally, I should be downloading all the pages in parallel.

```
session = botocore.session.get_session()
client = session.create_client('s3')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=my_bucket, Prefix=my_prefix,
      PaginationConfig={'StartingToken':None, 'MaxItems': 1200})

it = iter(pages)
p1 = next(it)
...
p2 = next(it)
...

marker = p2['NextKeyMarker']
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=my_bucket, Prefix=my_prefix,
      PaginationConfig={'StartingToken': marker, 'MaxItems': 1000})
```

PS: Are there any other tricks like separating the prefix to `my_prefix + '/[A-I]'`, `my_prefix + '/[J-Q]'`, ... for parallel download?